# Sending commands to an IP phone on the network using PHP

Tags: php, iphone, com, tapi

I have a number of phones on my network and I would like to be able to send a number to one based on extension for it to dial.

I have looked into TAPI and the PHP COM events but I don't understand it all that well and how to apply it to my setup.

Does anyone have any experience with using PHP to send commands to an IP phone on their network?

Answer (score 1):

If these are Cisco IP Phones you can look at using the Ip Phone Services API: http://developer.cisco.com/web/ipps

Look specifically at "Dial" Telephony URI in the Application Development Notes

Each IP phone has a web server on it, you can use standard http(s) posts to send XML commands to the phone.  You can completely control the phone in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that client-server communication is a bit unidirectional. From iPhone to server you can easily send messages (and get responses), but to send a message from server to iPhone you have to implement **socket connection** between them, so the iPhone will always "listen" to what the server is "saying". Also, push notifications are a way to send messages from server to device, but it's not your case, I guess.

Comment: IP phones are not (Apple) iPhones.